# Rewrite url to another domain while maintaining the last part of url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a question similar to this
[URL rewrite for part of domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129363/url-rewrite-for-part-of-domain-name)

Tried to use that rule but it didn't work. I think the url rule could be different.

I have the url:

```
olddomain.com/test/ref/s/page

olddomain.com/test/ref/s/page1

olddomain.com/test/ref/s/page2
```

I need to rewrite them and maintain the last part of the url, eg:

```
https://www.newdomain.com/test/ref/s/page

https://www.newdomain.com/test/ref/s/page1

https://www.newdomain.com/test/ref/s/page2
```

Edit:
The ending of the url is dynamic so using individual redirection for each link is not practical.

Much thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your `.htaccess` file to do this, similar to the answer you are referencing. If you just want to send your old urls to your new urls individually, you can achieve this quite easily using the `Redirect 301` function inside `.htaccess`, and uploading to the root of "old domain", like so:

```
Redirect 301 /test/ref/s/page https://www.newdomain.com/test/ref/s/page
Redirect 301 /test/ref/s/page1 https://www.newdomain.com/test/ref/s/page1
Redirect 301 /test/ref/s/page2 https://www.newdomain.com/test/ref/s/page2
```

This will individually 301 the index at each of the old urls to the corresponding new url.

If you want to redirect everything from "old domain" to "new domain" just use a rewrite like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

You would, of course, need to configure this depending on your use of SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that would work too but not practical in my current situation. The ending of the url is actually dynamic and I could end up having to add thousands of redirect rule.

Comment: @Wood Ah I see. Then just rewrite everything at once, no? Check the revised answer.